# How to ask a person (maybe a waiter) what they recommend?

Tags: traducción

If I'm in a restaurant and want recommendations from the waiter/waitress, would I say '*¿Qué me aconseja?*' or would I simply say '*¿Que recomiendas?*' / '*¿Qué me recomienda?*'. I assume that '*recomiendas*' is more casual than '*aconseja*'?

Also, is the '*me*' in '*¿Qué me recomienda?*' insinuating that I'm asking for a recommendation for specifically **me** and without it I'd be asking for a general recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Asking a waiter

When you are in a restaurant, you need to show respect to the waitress/waiter by using "usted", since you don't know her/him. For example ¿Usted que me recomendaría del menú? / ¿Usted que me recomienda?

You need to be careful with:

1. ¿Qué me recomiendas? The **s** in recomienda**s** is implying a more casual situation. You're insinuating that you know her/him. You should not use it since it's a formal situation.
2. ¿Qué me recomienda? It's more formal, even if you're not using usted, you still showing respect by not using the **s** in recomienda.

It's not common to say ¿Qué me aconseja?, it'd seem like you're asking for a personal advice.

- Asking a person

  1. If you're in a restaurant with some friend, relative, the situation is more casual. You could say

¿Qué me recomienda**s** del menú?
¿Qué me recomendaría**s** del menú?

For example:

No sé que pedir, ¿Qué me recomiendas del menú? / I don't know what to order. What would you recommend me on the menu?

2. If you're in a restaurant with someone you don't know very well, the situation is formal since you don't know that person. You could say

¿Que me recomendaría usted?
¿Qué me recomienda del menú?

For example:

Disculpe, no sé exactamente que pedir, ¿Qué me recomendaría usted del menú? / Excuse me, I don't know exactly what to order, what do you recommend on the menu?

Now, I don't understand what do you mean with using "me" as a recommendation for you and not using it as a general recommendation. Could you be more specific?